# Error 2042 when using application.match in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the index of the integer in an array in VBA.

I created the array as such.

```
Dim spot(11) as Integer
For index = 1 To NoOfSpotValues
   spot(index) = Cells(15 + index, 7)
Next
```

When I do:

```
posOfSpot = Application.Match(0, spot, False)
```

It gives me an error as
    `posOfSpot = Error 2042`.

How do I solve it? Tried searching. Need some guidance on this.

**EDIT:**

```
Function Find(ByVal Value As Variant, arr As Variant) As Integer
If arr.Exists(Value) Then
    index = arr(Value)
Else
    index = -1
End If
```

Comment: Could you not loop through the array to see if an element exists with value, you are looking for?

Comment: Did that already. MsgBox spot(index) and the value exist

Comment: Are you still facing the error? i.e. if you don't use `Match` function or any excel formula, there should not be an error.

Comment: @shahkalpesh I am still facing the error. I need to find the index. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using formula instead of VBA, you could do

```
=MATCH(0 ,G16:G26,0)
```

If the value could not be found, it will return `#N/A`, index otherwise.

```
Sub Find(ByVal Value As Integer)
Dim spotData
Dim index As Integer

Set spotData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For index = 1 To 11
    spotData.Add Cells(15 + index, 7).Value, index
Next

If spotData.Exists(Value) Then
    index = spotData(Value)
Else
    index = -1
End If

Set spotData = Nothing
Debug.Print index
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont recall if VB has something built-in to deal with what you are looking for.

Comment: It gives an runtime error as object required when spotData.Exists(Value) is executed

Comment: Have you copied the code right? I ran this piece of code before submitting it.

Comment: I changed the code slightly for my needs. Made it as a function. I can show how I changed it. It is in the question.

Comment: Are you passing an instance of `Scripting.Dictionary` for arr, for your new function? Post the full code which I can copy and run.

Comment: No I am not. I am doing it this way: Find(currentSpot, spot)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68943/discussion-between-shahkalpesh-and-lakesh).

Comment: Just type it. In office now. Can't access the discussion in chat.

Comment: IIRC, VBA does not have support to search the array. That is the reason, I used scripting.dictionary. If you are modifying things to suit your needs, you can split the code but not change it from dictionary to array.

Comment: Now I understand. Will change it to the spot array to dictionary. I know how to handle dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim spot(1 to 11) as Long
Dim posOfSpot& , index&
For index = 1 To NoOfSpotValues
   spot(index) = Cells(15 + index, 7).value
Next index


posOfSpot = Application.Match(0, spot, 0)
msgbox posOfSpot
```

tried this, works.

BUT, the code would be faster with a simple loop inside the array to find your value